# static imports in c#

Tags: java, c#, .net, static-import

Does C# has feature like Java's static imports?

so instead of writing code like

```
FileHelper.ExtractSimpleFileName(file)
```

I could write

```
ExtractSimpleFileName(file)
```

and compiler would know that I mean method from FileHelper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reference a method in a static class without referencing the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671769/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-method-in-a-static-class-without-referencing-the-c)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Starting with C# 6.0, this is possible:

```
using static FileHelper;

// in a member
ExtractSimpleFileName(file)
```

---

However, previous versions of C# do not have static imports.

You can get close with an alias for the type.

```
using FH = namespace.FileHelper;

// in a member
FH.ExtractSimpleFileName(file)
```

Alternatively, change the static method to an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the type - you would then be able to call it as:

```
var value = file.ExtractSimpleFileName();
```

Answer (score 13):

No, such feature doesn't exist in C#. You need to specify the class that the static method belongs to unless you are already inside a method of this same class.

In C# though you have [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which kind of mimic this.

Answer (score 8):

C# 6.0 under Roslyn Platform [supports Static import](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). It requires statement like:

```
using static System.Console;
```

so the code might look like:

```
using static System.Console;
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("My test message");
        }
    }
}
```

The earlier planned version for C# 6.0 had static import *without* `static` keyword.

For other new features in C# 6.0 see: [New Language Features in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

Answer (score 6):

Time marches on... it looks like C# might get static imports in the next version, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx for a preview.

```
using System;
using System.Console; // using the Console class here

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Console.WriteLine is called here
        WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

The [official documentation](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home) for the 'Roslyn' C# compiler lists the feature as 'done'

Comment: Jack be Nimble, Jack be Quick … with C# static usings!

I cannot express how thrilled I am about this feature. I have been eagerly waiting for this expressiveness to enter the language for years, but never expected I would see the day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 6+ with C# 10+, you can add all the namepaces, (including the static ones) that you want to use globally in obj > Projectname.GlobalUsings.g.cs and you'll be able to use all the classes that are part of those namepaces without importing.  Here are some examples:

```
 global using global::System.Net.Http.Json;
 global using global::System.Threading;
 global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
 global using static global::System.Console;
```