# Is it possible to reference a method in a static class without referencing the class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to declare a static method within a class/namespace hierarchy such that the method can be addressed directly without having the refer to its classname?  For example if I have this namespace and class...

```
namespace UsefulMethods
{
    public static class DataBaseStuff
    {
        public static DataTable GetDataTable(String command, SqlConnection conn)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dostuff...
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

then I write some code that uses this class and I put statement...

```
using UsefulMethods;
```

...at the top of my code, I can get a DataTable returned to me by...

```
DataTable myDataTable = DataBaseStuff.GetDataTable(command, conn);
```

I thought maybe I could refer to a static class with a using statement as well like...

```
using UsefulMethods.DataBaseStuff;
```

...so that I could just refer to the method without the class name like this...

```
DataTable myDataTable = GetDataTable(command, conn);
```

...but this doesn't seem to work.  The intellisense doesn't find the static class in the using statement, so I guess that just works for namespaces.  So, is there some way for me to have my code to know what static class I'm referring to without referencing it every time I call one of the static methods?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: There is always `Reflection`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) you can do that with [static import](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

```
using static UsefulMethods.DataBaseStuff;
```

Until then you can't. You have to use class name with static method.

See: [New Language Features in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

> **Using static**
>
> The feature allows all the accessible static members of a type to be
>   imported, making them available without qualification in subsequent
>   code:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
using static System.DayOfWeek;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine(Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)); 
        WriteLine(Friday - Monday); 
    }
}
```

> This is great for when you have a set of functions related to a
>   certain domain that you use all the time. System.Math would be a
>   common example of that. It also lets you directly specify the
>   individual named values of an enum type, like the System.DayOfWeek
>   members above.